# Struts2 Jquery v4.0.2 Tree Tag Persistence

Tags: struts2-jquery

I want to persist the state of the Tree Menu on page reload/refresh. May I know how I can achieve this using the Struts2 Jquery Tree Plugin. 
Can anyone help me with an example?

Also, May I know how to expand only the root TreeItem?

What methods can I call to expand/collapse the individual nodes?

Comment: If you want to persist the state then you'll have to keep the serialized state either in local storage, a cookie if it's small, or on the server, and deserialize it on reload. There are any number of ways this could be done.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Could you please provide me some sample examples of it?